# How do i correctly use ContentTemplateSelector with ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have lots of ContentControl objects and I need a border around a few of them, not all. I was able to get it working with the below code:

```html
<ContentControl Margin="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Beige">
    <!-- ContentControl.Template to get the border -->
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                <ContentPresenter
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Paid" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Label Content="{Binding ReceivedAmount}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </StackPanel>
</ContentControl>
```

I want to move the entire ContentTemplate section to an other resource file and merge them. I added a new resource file and moved the below part of code to it.

```html
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="BalanceAmountControls">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
        <ContentPresenter
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When I try to change the actual ContentControl code to this, I get an error saying

> "An object of type System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate cannot be
>   applied to a property that expects the type
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector"

```html
<!-- Balance amount -->
<ContentControl Margin="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Beige" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource BalanceAmountControls}">
    <!-- ContentControl.Template to get the border -->
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Balance" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Label Content="{Binding BalanceAmount}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </StackPanel>
</ContentControl>
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You seem to be confusing DataTemplates and ControlTemplates. The `ContentTemplate` property of a ContentControl holds a DataTemplate, while a ControlTemplate is assigned to its `Template` property. Besides that, as the error message clearly says, the `ContentTemplateSelector` property expects a DataTemplateSelector. This is yet another thing, i.e. a C# class that you have to write. At this point it seems a good idea to take a look at the online documentation of all those things: [Styling and Templating](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating).

Comment: Ok, I get it. But I cannot have a border element defined within a DataTemplate. What is the best way to apply a border to 20 ContentControl elements out of 100 for example?

Answer (score 1):

> An object of type ***ControlTemplate*** cannot be
>   applied to a property that expects the type
>   ***DataTemplateSelector***

This error message is very explicit. You are assigning a `ControlTemplate` to a`ContentControl.DataTemplateSelector`. Type mismatch. You are assigning

`<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="BalanceAmountControls">`

to

`<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource BalanceAmountControls}">`.

Solution:
You need to implement your own  [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8#examples):

```
public class ContentControlDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Task)
        {
            if (// your condition)
                return
                    element.FindResource("BalanceAmountControls") as  DataTemplate;
            else
                return
                    element.FindResource("NonBalanceAmountControls") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Apply the template selector:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentControlDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

Now you need to create the proper [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=netframework-4.8#examples) resources which describe the individual visual appearance of the data that you have to bind to the `ContentControl.Content` property.

Comment: This was indeed a clue to my issue. The question + answer is quite different. 
"an object of type templateselector cannot be applied to a property that expects system.windows.datatemplate"